# PROC PRINT ignoring LABEL statement

Tags: pdf, printing, sas, label

I'm using proc print to simply print a SAS dataset as a PDF.  I am using the label statement to specify column names, but every time I run it, it is still using the field names.

What am I doing wrong?  I suspect I am missing something trivial in the settings or something, but I can't find any good info on this issue.

```
proc print data=work.table noobs;
label   cnt_approved    =   'Approved'
        total           =   'Total'
        perc_approved   =   'Percent Approved';
run;
```

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: You have to tell PROC PRINT to use labels.  PROC statement option LABEL.

Comment: Ahh, duh.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the PROC statement LABEL in the opening line to tell PROC PRINT to use the labels.

```
proc print data=work.table noobs label;
      label   cnt_approved    =   'Approved'
              total           =   'Total'
              perc_approved   =   'Percent Approved';
run;
```